# ms-access query "type mismatch"

Tags: jquery, ms-access, expression

simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Val([TextField]) > 0;
```

i recevie error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

same in CInt \ CLng wraping.

way? or another way?

Comment: can you try `"0"` instead of `0` .

Comment: The problem is that `Val([TextField])` is causing an error because at least one value in `[TextField]` cannot be converted by `Val`.  It is likely that there is some text in it that cannot be converted to a number.  Investigate the `IsNumeric` function which will tell you whether a value is a valid number before you call `Val`.

Comment: @ArindamNayak same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have Null values, so try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE [TextField] Not Is Null And Val([TextField]) > 0;
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Val([TextField] & "") > 0;
```

Testing for `Val([TextField]) > "0"` doesn't make sense as Val returns a number.